# Find maximum of function for a range

Tags: functions

Given the following function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & x = 0 \\
1, & x = 1 \\
f(i), & x = 2i \\
f(i)+f(i+1), & x = 2i + 1
\end{cases}
$$

Calculate $max(f(1), f(2),...,f(n))$

I've plotted $f(n)$ for $n$ between $1$ and $100000$, here's what I found
[image]
There's clearly a pattern, but I don't really know yet what's the rule for it.

Comment: What is $f(i)$ ?

Comment: This is the sequence of numerators in the [Calkin–Wilf tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree), known as [Stern's diatomic series (or Stern-Brocot sequence)](https://oeis.org/A002487).

Comment: @VivaanDaga When $x$ is even, so $x=2i$, you have $f(x)=f(i)$, when $x=2i+1$ is odd, you have $f(x)=f(i)+f(i+1)$. This is a recursive definition.